# PHP XML parser - Echo message when attribute not found

Tags: php, xml

Let's say I have the following xml file:

```
<menu_items>
  <food type="pizza" ingredient="cheese"/>
  <food type="spaghetti" ingredient="tomatoes"/>
  <food type="pizza" ingredient="pepperoni"/>
  <food type="hamburger" ingredient="beef"/>
  <!-- etc. -->
</menu_items>
```

And I have a piece of php code that grabs this xml file and looks for type="pizza" only. Then it echoes the ingredient of every pizza it finds.

```
$url = "http://example.com/data.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->food as $food){
    If ($food["type"] == "pizza")
        {echo $food["ingredient"] . "<br>";}
    else
        {echo "No pizzas found!";}
}
```

I would like it to echo "no pizzas found" when zero pizzas are found in the xml file. As expected, with the current php code I have, it echoes "pizza not found" over and over again for every type that is not pizza.

So if no pizzas are found at all then echo "no pizzas found" only once.

Comment: just initialize a boolean flag as false, if its still false after the loop then echo as not found

Comment: Maybe a quick look at the manual would help [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://example.com/data.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$pizzaflag = false;

foreach($xml->food as $food) {
    if ($food["type"] == "pizza") {
        echo $food["ingredient"] . "<br>";
        $pizzaflag = true;
    }
}

if ($pizzaflag == false) {
    echo "No pizzas found!";
}
```